# How to play mediaPlayer in Android after pressing the home button and when phone is receive and then resume the video that point?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Can you tell me how to play mediaPlayer  in Android when I press the home button of emulator or phone? I want it so that when it receives a phone call to stop the video and be able to resume video again that point. How should I do this in this code?

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class VideoActivity2 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
setContentView(R.layout.activity_video2);

VideoView videoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoView2);
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+
getPackageName() +"/"R.raw.song1));
videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.video_activity2, menu);
return true;
}

public void startVideoActivity3(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent(VideoActivity2.this, VideoActivity3.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
public void startVideoActivity(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent(VideoActivity2.this, VideoActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
public void startMainActivity(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent(VideoActivity2.this,    

MainActivity.class);intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
 finish();
}
startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I never use VideoView class, but according to documentation, this should work:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
   super.onPause();
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView2);
    videoView.pause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView2);
   videoView.resume();
}
```

Comment: It would be better to modify local videoView to class member in onCreate() and then reuse it in onPuase() and onResume().

Comment: Yes, indeed. I just wanted to make the code clear to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to cyanide's answer, I found the videoView.pause() to not always capture the position of the video - resulting in a black videoView onResume. By adding the videoStopPosition variable this issue is avoided.

```
//Allows video to resume from same location as the pause
private static int videoStopPosition = 0;

@Override
public void onPause() {
   super.onPause();
   VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView2);
   videoStopPosition = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
   videoView.pause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView2);
   videoView.seekTo(videoStopPosition);
   videoView.resume();
}
```